# Nuxt 3 and Vuetify 3 : breakpoints not working?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

I try to use properly Vuetify 3 with Nuxt 3.

For this, I installed the "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.0" and I had some configurations.

In the nuxt.config.ts :

```
build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify']
}
```

In plugins/vuetify.js :

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        components,
        directives,
    })

    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

It seems working for a part a Vuetify, for example, I can user a <v-carousel.....

But it seems that there are missing parts :

- JS behaviors does not works : my carousel isn't animated
- The breakpoints are wrong, for example in desktop mode : $vuetify.display.smAndDown is TRUE.

Maybe my installation is not good ? Do you have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Please let me know if find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The API changed. You have to use the useDisplay() hook now. https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/display-and-platform/

This other answer helped me: [Nuxt 3 with Vuetify 3 and SSR reactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73722057/nuxt-3-with-vuetify-3-and-ssr-reactivity). It links to a working example where they got it working with useDisplay() and a watcher with the `immmediate:true` option: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-uqphrm?file=app.vue

Answer (score 3):

You can also put useDisplay() in a ref().

```
<script setup lang="ts"> 
  import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify'

  const display = ref(useDisplay())
</script>

<template>
  {{ display.smAndDown }}
</template>
```

Comment: excellent! this made `v-if` react to display changes