# Nuxt 3 with Vuetify 3 and SSR reactivity

Tags: nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to use Nuxt 3 together with Vuetify 3 in SSR mode. I face a problem using display's breakpoints. What is more, this functionality works with Nuxt 2 and Vuetify 2.

The code below shows only `div` element with red background instead of green, although the screen size is large. The reason is that the initial DOM rendering, which happens on the server side, assumes that the screen's size is small. The hydration on the client side somehow doesn't take into account, that the real size is large, although you can see in the browser's web inspector a log information `result green`.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div :class="divClass">Reactivity</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify'

const counter = ref(1)
const { lgAndUp } = useDisplay()

const divClass = computed(() => {
  const result = lgAndUp.value ? 'green' : 'red'
  console.log('result', result)

  return result
})
</script>

<style>
  .green {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .red {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

This seems like a bug, but maybe I've done some silly mistake here. Could you look at this and verify? Thanks in advance :)

The project sources can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/tlempart/nuxt3-reactivity)

Answer (score 2):

You could use ref property and watch the `lgAndUp` value to update it :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div :class="divClass">Reactivity</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify';
const { lgAndUp } = useDisplay();
const divClass = ref('');

watch(lgAndUp, (val) => {
  console.log(val);
  divClass.value = val ? 'green' : 'red';
},{immediate:true});
</script>

<style>
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-uqphrm?file=app.vue)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Boussadjra, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The `watch` has never been called and the `div`'s background is white.

Comment: could share your code in github?

Comment: The sources are available [here](https://github.com/tlempart/nuxt3-reactivity), but even your [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vgaxjb?file=app.vue) shows only white background.

Comment: Try to add `immediate:true` option to the watch https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-uqphrm?file=app.vue

Comment: Thank you @Boussadjra, now it works. I am wondering, why the `watch` is required here. Vuetify 2 works like a charm and such tricks weren't necessary. Should the Vuetify's `lgAndUp` be reactive by default? What do you think?

Comment: It should be reactive; this looks like a bug since both Nuxt3 and Vuetify3 are still under development. please upvote my answer if you find it useful

Comment: I will if I only get enough reputation.

Comment: The problem here is the initial state is always red, even for lgAndUp resolution.